# Private PyPi Repository in Closed Network

Tags: python, pip

I am on a closed network (aka no access to the internet) thus I need to create my own PyPi server. I am following the instructions here:

[How to set up and use a private PyPI repo](https://gist.github.com/Jaza/fcea493dd0ba6ebf09d3)

The only differences:

- I did not do was set up Apache authentication. No need for it.
- I put everything in /src/pypi (all pointers were updated)

I was able to get Apache operational and (supposedly) got my ~/.pip/pip.conf file operational. Here are the contents:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://pypi.myserver.com/pypi/
trusted-host = pypi.myserver.com
```

When I try to run the command:

```
pip install foobar-utils
```

I get the following:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at xxx>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errorno -2] Name or service not known',)' /simple/foobar-utils
```

I know it's hitting apache, I see it in my logs.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely replace PyPI you must use `index-url` instead of `extra-index-url`. With `extra-index-url` `pip` still search packages at `https://pypi.org`, `extra-index-url` is an **additional** server to search.

Your pip.conf must be

```
[global]
index=https://pypi.myserver.com/pypi/
index-url=https://pypi.myserver.com/pypi/
trusted-host = pypi.myserver.com
```

`index` is for `pip search`, `index-url` for `pip install`.